# Identifying an API

Tags: perl, nagios

NetApp Tech Support is assisting me with an SDK issue between Nagios and a filer cluster. One question he asked me is, 'What API are you calling when you run /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_netapp_ontap.pl?'. How would I determine which API is being used when I run this command in RHEL 6?

Comment: By reading `/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_netapp_ontap.pl`

Comment: I'm hoping that was a genuine and sincere attempt to help a fellow admin, and not a lame attempt at sarcasm. Reading that script was the 1st thing I did.

Comment: The question really means 'exactly what is your script doing to collect data frmo the Netapp'?  Just tell them what requests are being made to the filer by that script.

Comment: @Flup you should post that as an answer...

Answer (score 1):

Although the code can run on Linux, it's not really a Linux question.

Assuming the code comes from this [OutsideIT](https://outsideit.net/check-netapp-ontap/) page, then just from the variable names it looks to me like the NaServer.pm portion is trying to use the ZAPI interface.

```
[...]
$::ZAPI_xmlns = "http://www.netapp.com/filer/admin";
$::ZAPI_dtd = "file:/etc/netapp_filer.dtd";
my $FILER_dtd = "file:/etc/netapp_filer.dtd";
my $DFM_ZAPI_dtd = "file:/etc/netapp_dfm.dtd";
my $AGENT_ZAPI_dtd = "file:/etc/netapp_agent.dtd";
$::ZAPI_snoop = 0;
```